# C++ CLR Using Zlib's Minizip with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, clr, zlib

I've had a terrible time with this. I can't seem to find anything about actually getting [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) into my project on the web. Every tutorial assumes I already got it working. It's terribly frustrating!

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition to create a simple program to read what files are in a ZIP file (My original intentions were a JAR file, but I just want to get a ZIP file to work before going for a JAR). I've gotten Zlib into my project fine, I've done it before. I just used

```
#pragma once
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "zlib.h"
#pragma managed(pop)
#pragma comment(lib, "f:/programming/zlib-include/lib/zdll.lib")
```

and I got Zlib to work. But now I get stuck here. Just adding #include "unzip.h" from the minizip folder gives me linker errors, which is what I expected. So I looked on the minizip website (link above), and it mentioned some zlibwapi.dll stuff. So, I put that into my project, and defined ZLIB_WINAPI (which I read was needed elsewhere), but no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, solved it myself. I was linking the dllx64 version of zlibwapi.lib, not the dll32 version. Didn't know there was an important difference, but I guess there is :)